# How to override the default loopback model API paths

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, loopbackjs, strongloop

How can we override the default loopback REST API model end points? For example, I would like to invoke a custom model method named **list** when the following GET API is invoked.

[image]

I am referring to the documentation https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Exposing-models-over-REST.html

1.API endpoint from loopback explorer: http://localhost:3000/api/Assets

2.Model method definition:

```
Asset.list = function(cb) {
    console.log("called");
}

Asset.remoteMethod('list', {
    http: {path: '/'},
    returns: {type: 'Object', root: true}
});
```

Comment: you have try above?

Comment: Did you consider using `Model` rather than `PersistedModel` as a base?

Comment: I have a similar situation, where after the db insert, need to create record in redis, but if the redis insert fails then the persisted records should also rollback.
we can handle this with begin and commit transaction. But this won't work with the existing default API lifecycle( with the operation hooks), but the default API's are already being used by the frontend application. is there a way to override the existing API's, same as mentioned in the above question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use not default path (not used by default methods) you should add new remote method to JSON model config and define method in JS model file:

```
"methods": {
  "myCustomMethod": {
    "accepts": [
      {
        "arg": "req",
        "type": "object",
        "http": {
          "source": "req"
        }
      }
    ],
    "returns": [
      {
        "type": "Array",
        "root": true
      }
    ],
    "http": {
      "verb": "GET",
      "path": "/myCustomPath"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
Candidate.myCustomMethod = (req) => {//method code}
```

---

If you want to override default loopback path (autogenerated methods) you also should disable default method.

```
Candidate.disableRemoteMethodByName('find');
```

So now you can change in JSON config "/myCustomPath" to "/" and your remote method would refer to your function instead of default.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log("called");` should appear in your terminal only, not as a return on your web browser - that's maybe why you aren't seeing it at the moment.

If you want to see something on your web browser, you have to return a value for you callback, like:

```
module.exports = function (Asset) {

    Asset.list = function(cb) {
        console.log("called");
        cb(false, {'called': true}); // cb(error, returned value(s));
    }

    Asset.remoteMethod('list', {
        http: {verb: 'get'},
        returns: {type: 'Object', root: true}
    });
}
```

This file should be in your *common/model/asset.js*

---

In your *server/model-config.json*, do not forget to reference your model:

```
     ...
     "Asset": {
        "dataSource": "yourdatasource", //change this by your datasource name
        "public": true
     }
     ...
```

Comment: Agreed to the above points and my list API is working fine. But, I am looking for a method to override the default GET API (please check the screen shot attached with the post)

Comment: I'm not sure you can override the default /POST /PUT /GET /PATCH /DELETE, but you can remove these endpoints with custom mixins and add new endpoints like you did.